# Automating Google AI notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do I use google cloud scheduler to trigger a function in google AI notebook that will extract data from google biquery, process that data and store it in google cloud storage. I had tried cloud functions already and it gets timed out so I am exploring the option of commissioning a VM instances and running a notebook on it. Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Notebooks API](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/reference/rest) to manage notebook resources in GCP.

There are ways to create, start and trigger executions for notebooks using that approach. I found that this may be of use for you in order to deploy a notebook and automate interactions with it in order to perform the steps you mentioned in your first message.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud now has "Managed Notebooks" with the option to easily set up automatic executions: [quickstart-schedule-execution-console](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/quickstart-schedule-execution-console)

However, at the time of writing, it's not fully functional, so I would suggest these steps:

- Set up a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python) using [Papermill](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to execute the desired notebooks
- Set up a [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart) and [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-console) to run the function

The rest can be handled in the Notebook script:

```
# Query BigQuery:
df = bigquery.Client().query('SELECT * FROM your_table').to_dataframe()

# Upload to Cloud Storage:
bucket = storage.Client().get_bucket('YOUR_BUCKET')
blob = bucket.blob('YOUR_FILEPATH_IN_BUCKET.csv')
blob.upload_from_string(df.to_csv(index=False), 'text/csv')
```